# Warning when connecting c++ signal to qml slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick

I connect a c++ signal to qml function in qt4.8.4. It's working fine but makes warning in application output as below:

> Object::connect: No such slot QDeclarativeItem_QML_9::onValue_changed(double)
>     Object::connect:  (sender name:   'MyWidget')

I have defined qml slot like this :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    id: root
    property real value : 0

    Connections
        {
            target: controllerObject
            onValue_changed :
            {
                root.value = value
            }
        }
}
```

And this is my c++ Signal and how it is connected to qml slot :

```
ui->view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("controllerObject",this);
ui->view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/myQml.qml"));
ui->view->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);");
ui->view->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
ui->view->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);

connect(this,SIGNAL(value_changed(double)),(QObject *)ui->view->rootObject(),SLOT(onValue_changed(double)));
```

Why is it making that warning?

How to omit the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have defined qml slot like this :

You are wrong. It is not slot definion, it's `connection` itself 
(the adding of QML handler for signal `value_changed` of object `controllerObject`).
That's why you code works. But in this line :

> connect(this, SIGNAL(value_changed(double)), (QObject*)ui->view->rootObject(), SLOT(onValue_changed(double)));

You are trying to connect existing signal `value_changed` to inexisting `onValue_changed`
(obviously, it exists in your code, but not in `rootObject` of view). 
That's why you got warning.

**Conclusion**:
You tried to connect signal **twice**, but only **one** method was successful, so code worked well.